# How to obtain volume encryption interoperability between Android and Linux (LUKS)

Tags: encryption, linux, android, luks

On Linux, I use LUKS to encrypt containers (a filesystem on a file), which is portable as it can be easily copied, stored on any external filesystem, such as FAT or NTFS on external drives or SD cards.  It is easy to mount unencrypted files on a rooted Android since losetup is available.  But, I don't understand why Android lacks support for LUKS.  There have been apps that provided it, but they died without support.

So, the question is, what is the best universal way to encrypt containers across Linux and Android platforms to provide the highest degree of interoperability and portability?  Is there something other than LUKS that works natively on Android but can be easily used on regular Linux distros such as Fedora?

What baffles me, is if I understand correctly, both LUKS and Android use the kernel for native encryption.  If that's true, you'd think interoperability would be the norm.

Comment: Although you are asking about encryption tools, your question is about portability and not security.

Comment: *why Android lacks support for LUKS* One reason is need. LUKS is a good protection for "dormant" file systems (powered-off machine, external disks) but once the FS is mounted by a running system, it can be accessed via that system. And Android systems are typically "always on" and fairly easy to break in if you have physical access.